# issue with hadoop secondary node

Tags: hadoop, logging, cluster-computing

I am new to `hadoop`. When I run `wordcount` test project, evrything works fine. But, I can't access the `JobTracker` at `http://localhost:50030`. in fact, when I get my `secondary node` log file, I get exception message :

```
java.io.IOException: Bad edit log manifest (expected txid = 3: [[21,22], [23,24]
[8683,8684], [8685,8686], [8687,8688], [8689,8690], [8691,8692], [8693,8694], [8695,8696], [8697,8698], [8699,8700]]...
....
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.downloadCheckpointFiles(SecondaryNameNode.java:438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.doCheckpoint(SecondaryNameNode.java:540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.doWork(SecondaryNameNode.java:395)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode$1.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsLoginUserOrFatal(SecurityUtil.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:357)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Btw, when I run `jps`, I get `53745 JobHistoryServer 77259 Jps`

UPDATE : here's my config

in `core-site.xml`

```
<configuration>
  <property>
     <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>  
<value>/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/hdfs/tmp</value>
    <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>fs.default.name</name>                                     
     <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>                             
  </property>                                                        
</configuration>
```

in `hdfs-site.xml`

```
<configuration>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>1</value>
     </property>
 </configuration>
```

`mapred-site.xml`

```
<configuration>
       <property>
         <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
         <value>localhost:9010</value>
       </property>
 </configuration>
```

and nothing is set in my `yarn-site.xml`

Comment: You are using `yarn` (`map/reduce V2`), so there wont be any `JobTracker`. Anyway post your hadoop configs.

Comment: @RajeshN I have just updated my post !

Comment: Your configuration looks ok. If you were using `start-all.sh`, try starting hadoop processes with `$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh`

Comment: @RajeshN I am using `start-dfs.sh` so I don't understand what is happening

Comment: Somehow start-dfs.sh is picking up yarn instead of Map/Reduce V1. Try this instead, `$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh start servicename`. Here, `servicename` denotes `namenode`, `datanode`, `jobtracker`, `tasktracker` or `secondarynamenode`. Start only the services needed.

Comment: @RajeshN I started the daemons as you prescribed, but I still get no data available in my web ui and no nodes showing. How can it be ?

Comment: sure it is related to this `DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute mapred command is deprecated.
Instead use the mapred command for it.

Sorry, the jobtracker command is no longer supported.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using latest version of Hadoop, then Job Tracker will not be available. Job tracker is replaced by `Resource Manager` and `History Server`.

If you want to access past job details, go to `http://hostname:19888`. This is the web UI address for job history server.

Please refer [Hadoop Cluster Setup](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html#Web_Interfaces) for further details.

Comment: thank you but my question is now that I have `no data available` in my node's webui : localhost:8088. I see the node running but no data in my  `Application`

Comment: by the way a lot of `jobs` are missing in the `1:9888` web ui

Comment: Job history server will only list jobs that are executed when its running. It wont list jobs that were executed when there was no history server running.

Comment: sorry tp bother you but my main problem is that on my `localhost:8088`, I see the node running but no data in my Application. So how can it be ?